# How to get the value of a "hidden" href?

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests

I'm working with web scraping to, at first, collect the total pages. I have tested the code I made for another site and however I am having a problem getting the next page link (href).

Here's the code:

```
from urllib.parse import urljoin
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

userName = 'brendanm1975' # just for testing

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/61.0.3163.100 Safari/537.36'}

pages = []

with requests.Session() as session:
  page_number = 1
  url = "https://www.last.fm/user/"+userName+"/library/artists?page="
  while True:
      response = session.get(url, headers=headers)
      soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')
      pages.append(url)

      next_link = soup.find("li", class_="pagination-next")
      if next_link is None:
        break

      url = urljoin(url, next_link["href"])
      page_number += 1
```

As you can see, the href of this site presents the link as "?page=2", which does not allow me to get its content (https://www.last.fm/user/brendanm1975/library/artists?page=2).

I've already inspected the variables, and I'm getting the values.

```
print(url) # output: https://www.last.fm/user/brendanm1975/library/artists?page=
next_link.find('a').get('href') # output: '?page=2'
```

Does anyone know how to get around this?

Comment: Maybe use their [API](https://www.last.fm/api) instead?

Comment: What's the problem with getting href by `next_link.find('a').get('href')`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### What happens?

You try to `urljoin(url, next_link["href"])` but `next_link` do not have an attribute `href` cause you are selecting the `<li>` not the `<a>`.

#### How to fix?

**Option#1** - Just select the `<a>` in your `urljoin()`:

```
url = urljoin(url, next_link.a["href"])
```

**Option#2** - Select the `<a>` directly:

```
next_link = soup.select_one('li.pagination-next a')
```

#### Example

```
from urllib.parse import urljoin
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

userName = 'brendanm1975' # just for testing

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/61.0.3163.100 Safari/537.36'}

pages = []

with requests.Session() as session:

    url = "https://www.last.fm/user/"+userName+"/library/artists?page=1"
    while True:
        response = session.get(url, headers=headers)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')
        pages.append(url)

        next_link = soup.find("li", class_="pagination-next")
        if next_link is None:
            break

        url = urljoin(url, next_link.a["href"])
```

#### Output

```
['https://www.last.fm/user/brendanm1975/library/artists?page=1',
 'https://www.last.fm/user/brendanm1975/library/artists?page=2',
 'https://www.last.fm/user/brendanm1975/library/artists?page=3',
 'https://www.last.fm/user/brendanm1975/library/artists?page=4',
 'https://www.last.fm/user/brendanm1975/library/artists?page=5',
 'https://www.last.fm/user/brendanm1975/library/artists?page=6',
 'https://www.last.fm/user/brendanm1975/library/artists?page=7',
 'https://www.last.fm/user/brendanm1975/library/artists?page=8',
 'https://www.last.fm/user/brendanm1975/library/artists?page=9',
 'https://www.last.fm/user/brendanm1975/library/artists?page=10',
 'https://www.last.fm/user/brendanm1975/library/artists?page=11',
 'https://www.last.fm/user/brendanm1975/library/artists?page=12',
 'https://www.last.fm/user/brendanm1975/library/artists?page=13',
 'https://www.last.fm/user/brendanm1975/library/artists?page=14',
 'https://www.last.fm/user/brendanm1975/library/artists?page=15',
 'https://www.last.fm/user/brendanm1975/library/artists?page=16',
 'https://www.last.fm/user/brendanm1975/library/artists?page=17',
 'https://www.last.fm/user/brendanm1975/library/artists?page=18',...]
```